# Fetch the previous value if value is Null or 0

Tags: sql-server, cursor

```
CREATE TABLE stock (
    product_id int,
    opening_stock int,
    material_purchased int,
    material_sold int,
    Day date
);

insert into stock values (121,10,5,3,'2020-09-17');
insert into stock values (111,9,0,3,'2020-09-17');
insert into stock values (111,7,5,3,'2020-09-16');
```

Now I want to calculate day wise values such that if the value of `material_purchased` is `0` or `Not Null` on a particular day then it should consider the value of previous day.

Here I'm calculating `closing=opening_stock +material_purchased- material_sold`

My query:

```
Select t1.product_id,(t1.opening_stock+CALCULATED- material_sold) as closing
from
(

SELECT t1.product_id, t1.opening_stock,t1.material_sold
, (
    SELECT t2.material_purchased
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t2.product_id = (
        SELECT MAX(t3.product_id)
        FROM test t3
        WHERE t3.product_id <= t1.product_id
        AND material_purchased IS NOT NULL or material_purchased <> 0
       )
) AS CALCULATED
FROM test t1);
```

But this is not working giving error at from.

Let me know if I can do it using SQL query or Cursor.

Comment: I'm surprised your SSMS isn't flagging this up, but 1) You have 2 commas after `t1.material_purchase` 2) You don't have an alias on your outer sub-query and 3) you are  attempting to access t1 in your outer sub-query, when t1 is your middle sub-query. 4) `IS NOT` only applies to `null` so `IS Not 0` should be `<> 0`.

Comment: Please add an expected result for your sample data. Also, if your data includes `null`'s then your sample data might as well... With the current information you can just perform [this simple query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d52341d8363c4c9ed1a04c1a1522faa).